# java Program runtime is too fast? Issue with Memory

Tags: java, memory, time, jar

So I am running some simulations that require some sample datasets. For the sake of simplicity I am using this http://loremipsum.sourceforge.net/ Lorem Ipsum generator. I am setting a test parameter called DATASIZE that sets the amount of words or paragraphs this generator creates. I am using this generated data to create an "input" and "output" hash. The output data will use a slightly different hash. For example,

```
String input = hash(new LoremIpsum().getWords(DATASIZE))
String output = hash(new LoremIpsum().getWords(DATASIZE-2))
```

My question is, does Java keep the first data set in memory and then slightly modify it to quickly produce output? Maybe I was just pessemistic on the runtime but it seems very small. Virtually zero in System.currentTimeMillis(); Could it be the jar?

I also noticed something odd with my output. I am creating several objects that store this input and output hash. On some of these that I generate, for some reason the runtime is 16. Otherwise it is 0. Something with memory or just shoddy code?

Comment: How big is `DATASIZE`?

Comment: You can always look at the source code.  It has a static String variable that has the entire lorem text.  In the constructor, it split the string into words.  When you call getWords, it use a StringBuilder to create a strong consists of the number of words and return it.  How much memory is used depends on how many words you want.  It is no point in creating more than one LoremIpsum object because it contains the exact information.  But constructor is expensive because everytime you create a LoremIpsum object, its constructor has to split the hard coded string into words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses StringBuilder. So answer to your question is NO. There is no reuse/cache in getWords(..). - https://sourceforge.net/p/loremipsum/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/main/java/de/svenjacobs/loremipsum/LoremIpsum.java

Having said that, if you give really large number - say `1000000` then you may see difference. I checked using my latest all powerful macbook pro

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoremIpsum loremipsum = new LoremIpsum();
    
    long start;
    int number = 100000;
    
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        loremipsum.getWords(number);
        System.out.println("getWords():" +(System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    }

}
```

Output in ms

```
getWords():11
getWords():7
getWords():5
getWords():4
getWords():4
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yeah I think it was just the size of my dataset.